# prove $n!(n+1)^2-1$ using telescoping series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

the general formula of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k!)(k^2+k+1) $$
I got it using telescoping series. in the form of $n$. $$n!(n+1)^2-1$$
How do i prove the general formula using Telescoping series?

Comment: I am confused! You are already saying you got it using telescoping series right?

Comment: How do i prove my general formula using telescoping series? I proved it using induction

Comment: no i got the general formula. how do i prove it using telescoping series.. just like you can prove it using induction

Comment: Hint: $k!(k^2+k+1)= [k!(k+1)^2-1]-[(k-1)!k^2-1]$.  Note that I used a universal procedure. Once we know the sum of the first $n$ terms, any series can be mechanically made telescoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I think you required this: We can write it as,$(n!)((n+1)^2-n)$
So, now the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k!)((k+1)^2-k)$$ can be solved using telescoping.. Giving the result $(n!)(n+1)^2-1$